# How to exec a python script when linux starts

Tags: linux, python, files-folders

I want to exec a python script when linux starts.
I made an executable of my python file with `pyinstaller`, but I have no idea in which folder I should move the executable. In init.d folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [cron](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)  job. Check the linked website to view the man page. If you want to execute it after reboot use `@reboot` in your crontab.